# Magento 2 : Show a custom error message on cart page if bundle product options has changed

Tags: magento2, product, cart, quote, bundled-product

**I want to catch this error `"Some of the products below do not have all the required options."` which is coming from `checkData()` from the path `vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/AbstractItem.php`**

> I just want to change this error message, I tried to override the
> class `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item` file and changed it but it's showing error message everytime if i add to cart the bundle product only from the listing page. I believe this
> error occurs when we add bundle product to cart and in backend changes
> the bundle product options and refreshes the cart page then this error
> message will show.

> **MyVendor/MyModule/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_index">
        <observer name="custom_module_checkout_cart_index" instance="MyVendor\MyModule\Observer\CartPageLoadObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> **MyVendor\MyModule\Observer\CartPageLoadObserver.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\MyVendor\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CartPageLoadObserver implements ObserverInterface
{   
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("called111111");

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $allItems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            $productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
            $product = $productRepository->get($item->getSku());

            try {
                $item->getTypeInstance()->checkProductBuyState($item);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->setHasError(true)->setMessage($e->getMessage());
                // this is my custom message
                $this->getQuote()->setHasError(
                    true
                )->addMessage(
                    __('The products have recently changed. Please empty your cart and add the desired titles again.')
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:-** Ignore the use of object manager it's temporary.

**But Right now It's showing an error**

```
Error: Call to a member function checkProductBuyState() on null in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Observer/CartPageLoadObserver.php:43 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): MyVendor\MyModule\Observer\CartPageLoadObserver->execute() #1
```

Line no 43 code is
`$item->getTypeInstance()->checkProductBuyState($item);`

**After making some changes to the code shows the error at same line,**

`Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/Product/Type.php:1083 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Observer/CartPageLoadObserver.php(42): Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type->checkProductBuyState() #1 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88):  MyVendor\MyModule\Observer\CartPageLoadObserver->execute() #2`

```
$product = $productRepository->getById($item->getProductId());
try {
    $product->getTypeInstance()->checkProductBuyState($product);
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
    $logger->info("Errorrrrrrrrr".$e->getMessage());
}
```

**Let me know If anyone has a better idea.**

Comment: code edited wrongly.

Comment: dude, you could just translate that message via translation in theme or module, no need to override whole class.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/i18n/en_US.csv#L23

you could just do - 

"Some of the products below do not have all the required options.","The products have recently changed. Please empty your cart and add the desired titles again."

Comment: Great suggestion, i will try it out. @rex

Comment: can you tell me more specifically what is wrong with the code? @DhirenVasoya